# Sass Error: no mixin named roboto-family Backtrace: src/pages/forms/forms.scss:5

Tags: css, typescript, ionic-framework, sass

Hello I am completely new to ionic. I have started a project of ionic. I was trying to integrate a theme and I copied one .html file and an .scss file for that. I also created .ts file for that.

**Forms.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head lang="en">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Title</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bower_components/ionic/release/css/ionic.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dist/css/ionic.material-design-lite.css">
     <script src="../bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
     <script src="../dist/js/ionic.material-design-lite.bundle.js"></script>
     <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="use-material-icons" ng-app="material-starter">
       <div class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
           <button class="button icon ion-navicon"></button>
           <h1 class="title">Form Elements</h1>
       </div>
       <ion-content class="has-header padding">
           <div class="list">
               <label class="item item-input">
                     <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="ng-invalid">
               </label>
               <label class="item item-input item-floating-label input-calm">
                    <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
              </label>
              <label class="item item-input input-energized">
                    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user">
              </label>
             <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                    <input type="text">
             </label>
             <label class="item item-input">
                   <textarea placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
             </label>
         </div>

        <div class="list list-inset">
             <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
             </label>
             <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
             </label>
       </div>

       <div class="list">

           <div class="item item-input-inset">
               <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
               </label>
               <button class="button button-small">
                Submit
               </button>
           </div>
      </div>

      <div class="padding">
          <button class="button button-block button-positive">Submit</button>
       </div>
     </ion-content>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Forms.scss**

```
.platform-android, .platform-override {
.list:not(.card) .item.item-input {
@extend .mdl-textfield;
@extend .mdl-textfield--full-width;
@include roboto-family('Regular', 400);

background: transparent;
border: none;

.input-label {
  @include material-animation-default();
  @include roboto-family('Regular', 400);
}

&.is-focused, &.is-dirty {
  .input-label {
    @include roboto-family('Regular', 400);
    color: $input-text-highlight-color;
    font-size : $input-text-floating-label-fontsize;
    transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0) scale(1);
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.input-label {
  bottom: 0;
  color: $input-text-label-color;
  font-size: $input-text-font-size;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}

// The after label is the colored underline for the TextField.
&:after {
  background-color: $input-text-highlight-color;
  bottom: $input-text-vertical-spacing;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  left: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 10px;
}

&.is-focused:after {
  left: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
}

&.is-invalid {
  input, textarea {
    color: $input-text-error-color;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 $input-text-error-color;
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  &:after {
    background-color: $input-text-error-color;
  }
}

&.is-disabled {
  input, textarea {
    color: $input-text-disabled-color;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 $input-text-disabled-color;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted $input-text-disabled-color;
  }
}

input, textarea {
  @extend .mdl-textfield__input;

  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #444;
  color: $input-text-highlight-color;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #444;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-shadow: none;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
}

@each $color-name, $color in $color-map {
  &.input-#{$color-name} {
    @include input-focus-color($color);

    input, &.is-focused .input-label, &.is-dirty .input-label {
      color: $color;
    }

  }
}
}
}
```

**Forms.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'forms.html'
})
export class FormsPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

And when I run using command ionic serve it gives me following error

Sass Error

> no mixin named roboto-family Backtrace: src/pages/forms/forms.scss:5

I have saved fonts at path

> src/www/assets/fonts/roboto

Can anyone help me how to solve this?
What are the things that I am missing?

Comment: As the error states, you haven't defined the `roboto-family` mixin. You can read more about mixins (and other SASS basics)  [here](https://sass-lang.com/guide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, there is a line stating

```
@include roboto-family('Regular', 400);
```

at multiple places.

But there is no defined value or a **mixin** for the roboto-family to **include**.

Let me use an example.

A mixin lets you make groups of CSS declarations that you want to reuse throughout your site. You can even pass in values to make your mixin more flexible. A good use of a mixin is for vendor prefixes. Here's an example for *border-radius*.

```
    @mixin border-radius($radius) {
      -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
         -moz-border-radius: $radius;
          -ms-border-radius: $radius;
              border-radius: $radius;
        }

.box { @include border-radius(10px); }
```

To create a mixin you use the ***@mixin*** directive and give it a name. We've named our mixin border-radius. We're also using the variable $radius inside the parentheses so we can pass in a radius of whatever we want. After you create your mixin, you can then use it as a CSS declaration starting with ***@include*** followed by the name of the mixin. When your CSS is generated it'll look like this:

```
.box {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

So, to use ***@include roboto-family*** you need to define a ***@mixin roboto-family***

Hope this solves your issue.

ref: [For reference and detailed explanation](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6)

Comment: Thank you for such nice description.

Comment: Your Welcome..! Feel free to come up with new queries. :)